# error while building angular universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal

my app is fine with the normal serve but gets this error when doing `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

this is the `angular-errors.log` content:

> [error] TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_showWarnings' of object '#'
>
> ```
> at TapSubscriber._visitJsonRecursive.pipe.operators_1.tap.x [as _tapNext] (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\visitor.js:56:210)
> at TapSubscriber._next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:59:27)
> at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
> at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
> at InnerSubscriber._next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
> at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
> at app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:17:28
> at Object.subscribeToResult (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
> at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
> at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
> at MergeMapSubscriber._next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
> at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
> at Observable._subscribe (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\observable\scalar.js:6:20)
> at Observable._trySubscribe (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
> at Observable.subscribe (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
> at MergeMapOperator.call (app-directory\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:39:23)
> ```

and this is  my `package-lock.json` dependencies which i read somewhere might be related, to be more specific they said it might be [a mismatch between angular/cli and @angular-devkit/build-angular version.](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/730) but in my case they seem to be fine:

```
> "dependencies": {
>     "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
>     "@angular-persian/material-date-picker": "^1.8.1",
>     "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
>     "@angular/common": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
>     "@angular/forms": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
>     "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.0",
>     "@angular/router": "^8.2.0",
>     "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
>     "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
>     "@ng-select/ng-select": "3.6.1",
>     "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
>     "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
>     "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
>     "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
>     "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
>     "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
>     "@nrwl/angular": "8.7.0",
>     "@nsalaun/ng-logger": "^7.0.0",
>     "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
>     "@types/html-minifier": "^3.5.3",
>     "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.5",
>     "angular-notifier": "^6.0.1",
>     "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
>     "chartjs-plugin-labels": "^1.1.0",
>     "core-js": "^2.4.1",
>     "devextreme": "19.2.4",
>     "devextreme-angular": "19.2.4",
>     "devextreme-intl": "^19.1.7",
>     "express": "^4.15.2",
>     "fate-editor": "^1.10.1",
>     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
>     "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
>     "hashmap": "^2.4.0",
>     "install": "^0.13.0",
>     "jalali-moment": "^3.3.3",
>     "jquery": "^3.4.1",
>     "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
>     "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.1",
>     "mousetrap": "^1.6.3",
>     "ng-inline-svg": "^9.1.0",
>     "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
>     "ng-snotify": "^4.3.1",
>     "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
>     "ngx-drag-scroll": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
>     "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^2.0.1",
>     "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
>     "ngx-quill": "^7.3.11",
>     "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3",
>     "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
>     "npm": "^6.13.1",
>     "protractor": "^5.4.2",
>     "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
>     "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
>     "upcast": "^4.0.0",
>     "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
>     "zone.js": "^0.9.1"   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that we had the very same problem from the very beginning. I don't know how I failed to see that the version numbers are not the same.

So.. as said [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16087#issuecomment-555935683) I changed:

`"@angular-devkit/build-angular":"0.803.19` to `"@angular-devkit/build-angular" :0.803.5`

and got over the issue just like that.

Comment: Thanks, what is you "@angular/cli" version ?

Comment: Because I have set  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.5", and  "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2", but still th same error.

Comment: its 8.3.3 but i don't think problem is with the cli.. just to make sure.. did u remove the package-lock file before re-installing packages?

Comment: I downgraded to ` "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.4"` and it works, thanks!